# How to set appcompat windowBackground to textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I nned to set windowBackground of appcompat to some xml layout. I tried the below code but it dose not work.. any help. Thanks in advance..

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Color_600</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/Color_700</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/music_popup</item> //I need to set some XML layout here.
</style>
```

Log

> Process: com.example, PID: 10634
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/layout-v16/music_popup.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f04001a
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout-v16/music_popup.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f04001a
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2479)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
>               at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3630)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:148)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
>               at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag RelativeLayout
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1124)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
>               at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3630)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:148)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
>               at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: What error do you get? Also can you post the xml of the drawable you want to set as `android:windowBackground`?

Comment: you can not set xml layout, however you can set xml drawable,
Consider using <item name="windowBackground">@drawable/someDrawable</item>

Comment: how can i display textview in xml drawable ? or i need to display text in center of the screen . how can i achieve this..

Comment: You can not do this @layout/music_popup

Comment: windowBackground requires drawable or color resources.